# Can gevent workers be used in the python 3 app engine standard environment?

Tags: google-app-engine, gunicorn, gevent, google-app-engine-python

Attempting to use them gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 196, in init_process
    self.patch()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 75, in patch
    fileno=s.sock.fileno()))
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gevent/_socket3.py", line 114, in __init__
    self._sock = self._gevent_sock_class(family, type, proto, fileno)
OSError: [Errno 92] Protocol not available: 'protocol'
```

Are sockets not supported in the python 3 environment? Is this the reason it won't work?

My application spends a lot of time blocked on other web servers, so using async workers is necessary for decent performance. In the meantime I will try using `eventlet` workers instead.

EDIT: Including some more context around usage

app.yaml

```
runtime: python37
instance_class: F2

entrypoint: gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py -b :$PORT my_project.server:app
```

gunicorn.conf.py

```
# Recommended number of workers based on instance size:
# https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#entrypoint_best_practices
workers = 2
# Use an asynchronous worker as most of the work is waiting for websites to load
worker_class = 'gevent'
```

Since it is during gunicorn launch I don't believe the app definition context will be useful. However for completeness I'm launching a basic flask application. Something like:

my_project/server.py

```
from flask import Flask

from my_project.handlers import run

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(run, url_prefix='/run')
```

Comment: Can you include an example of how you're trying to use gevent?

Comment: Added some context, thanks for the quick reply! Let me know if anything else would be useful. There is a [note in the appengine flex documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#workers) about gevent workers, but I believe it is no longer relevant as the linked issue is closed.

Comment: Thanks, I can reproduce this. Looking into it now.

Comment: I have the same error with gevent, app engine standard and python3. I also tested with eventlet as worker class but it does not work fine neither.

Comment: Yeah, the eventlet worker for gunicorn is pretty much useless as it doesn't actually patch any of the blocking calls (see https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/pull/1884).

We eventually just switched to appengine flex (for other reasons) which allowed us to now use the gevent worker. If you want to see our setup take a look at `prod.yaml`, `gunicorn.conf.py` and `gevent_grpc_worker.py` here: https://github.com/Recidiviz/pulse-data

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I think we are limited to *GAE Flexible* or *Cloud Run on GKE* if we want to use *gevent*.

*GAE Standard* runs in a sandbox ([gVisor](https://gvisor.dev/docs/architecture_guide/)) and some operations are limited (I noticed this trying *Cloud Run* which had the same issue with *gevent*)

The error you are seeing is this one:

```
Container Sandbox Limitation: Unsupported syscall 
getsockopt(0x5,0x1,0x26,0x7e11bd8ddf20,0x7e11bd8ddf24,0x4)
```